# How can I use js if statement to add html code?

Tags: javascript

I have this line of code, just learning and practicing, wonder what's wrong, in span with `id="x"` numbers are changing, but JS script with if else statements isn't showing text variation. I want script to run **text** variation to `id="dobre+"` depending on number in `id="x"`.

```js
function f1() {
  var z, text;
  document.getElementById('x').value.innerHTML = z;
  if (z > 1) {
    text = "Clicked enough?";
  } else {
    text = "Click more";
  }
  document.getElementById('dobre+').innerHTML += "text";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('x').innerHTML++" onclick="f1">+</button>
  <span id="x"></span>
  <span>&#8364</span>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('x').innerHTML--" onclick="f1">-</button>
  <span id="dobre+"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: There are way too many things wrong with your code. Trying to make it work would require a complete change.

Comment: HTML and JS are so commonly used thaat they have become pretty resilient to these sort of mistakes, so it still just about runs, but if you add more and more code, and ever get an error, it will be ridiculously hard to debug. It's best to start with good code as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things wrong with your code. I somehow got your code to work but there's a lot of things incorrect in it that you need to know

1. `onclick` on your `button`s are supposed to be set only once, the JS statement in it needs to be separated by `;`
2. `f1` is a function so in order to call it and make it actually run you have to call it as `f1()`
3. It is a good practice to use `parseInt` on `strings` you get by using `innerHTML` or `innerText`
4. `document.getElementById('x').value.innerHTML= z;` there's no `.value` on a span + you are assigning the value of `z` to the `innerHTML` you should be doing the reverse.

You need to go through your code, check JavaScript console, look for errors and try fixing it first.

Answer (score -1):

Following are the issues in your code:

1. onclick attribute can be used just once. If you have multiple operations to perform then use semicolon ';'. Better is to write all the logic in one function. In your case f1()

2)`document.getElementById('x').value.innerHTML= z;`  The assignment should be reverse since you want to capture it. And it should be `document.getElementById('x').innerHTML;` Also try parsing it to Number/Int if you wish to perform mathematical operation.

3)`document.getElementById('dobre+').innerHTML+= "text";`   In this line there is no need to concatenate the previous text. `document.getElementById('dobre+').innerHTML= text;` Also text is a variable that you have initialized and not a string.

If all the above issues you fix your code should look like below and it would work as intended.

```
 <!Doctype html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Experimental page</title>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('x').innerHTML++;f1()"> 
        +</button>
        <span id="x"></span><span>&#8364</span>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('x').innerHTML--;f1()">     -</button>
        <span id="dobre+"></span>
        <script>
            function f1(){
            var z, text;
            z= document.getElementById('x').innerHTML;
            if (z > 1){
            text = "Clicked enough?";
            } else { text = "Click more";
            }
            document.getElementById('dobre+').innerHTML= text;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: I think it is due to the lack of explanation.

Comment: @DeepakKamat - There are many issues in his code. Helping would ease his task for understanding and he could do a code diff. for the same.

Comment: That's correct - but this forum is not supposed to be a homework help for others - maybe if there is something wrong they should know what's it.